# how does scoped proxy works internally in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, proxy, javabeans

consider a case when a prototype-scoped bean is injected into a singleton scoped bean,

when we try to access prototype-scoped bean using the singleton-scoped bean, we are returned with the same bean every time i.e. the bean injected at the time of singleton initialization.

if we want to get different instances everytime we use a scoped proxy.

I did not get the concept how this scoped proxy works behind the stage and how it magically gives us a new instance even if the bean is present inside a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring documentation:

> #### [3.4.4.5. Scoped beans as dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection)
>
> Being able to define a bean scoped to a HTTP request or Session (or indeed a custom scope of your own devising) is all very well, but one of the main value-adds of the Spring IoC container is that it manages not only the instantiation of your objects (beans), but also the wiring up of collaborators (or dependencies). If you want to inject a (for example) HTTP request scoped bean into another bean, you will need to inject an AOP proxy in place of the scoped bean. That is, you need to inject a proxy object that exposes the same public interface as the scoped object, but that is smart enough to be able to retrieve the real, target object from the relevant scope (for example a HTTP request) and delegate method calls onto the real object.
>
> …
>
> To create such a proxy, you need only to insert a child  element into a scoped bean definition (you may also need the CGLIB library on your classpath so that the container can effect class-based proxying; you will also need to be using Appendix A, XML Schema-based configuration). So, just why do you need this  element in the definition of beans scoped at the request, session, globalSession and 'insert your custom scope here' level? The reason is best explained by picking apart the following bean definition (please note that the following 'userPreferences' bean definition as it stands is incomplete):
>
> ```
> <bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session"/>
>
> <bean id="userManager" class="com.foo.UserManager">
>   <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>
> </bean>
> ```